# request permission methods called until the permission is granted

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-permissions

I have created methods for grant the permission of **location** and **storage** `read & write` using the `react-native-permission` library. when user is **deny** the permission then the permission dialog is disabled. But i am trying to do that, the **request** methods is call in loop until the user allow the permission of **location**. so, how can i do it. please suggest any solution

Code:

```
  reuestMultiplePermissions = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      requestMultiple([
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      ])
        .then((statuses) => {
          if (
         
            statuses[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION] ===
              RESULTS.GRANTED &&
            statuses[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] ===
              RESULTS.GRANTED
          ) {
            resolve(true);
          } else {
            reject({});
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

We can manage this using global variables update the status of the permission in a global variable as per the user input.

and check for the user input if permission granted the do something or ask permission again from user and if user has denied the permission permanently then open ask the user to open settings and allow permission to continue using app.